# Magento - Limit selected fields without collection when loading a Model

Tags: magento, model

I know how to limit fields when dealing with a collection, but what I'm wondering is if I can limit the selected fields when using getModel()->load($id).

My thought process is if I know the ID I use:

```
Mage::getModel('model')->load($id)
```

as opposed to:

`Mage::getModel('model')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', $id)->getFirstItem();`

The issue is load($id) returns everything. I know I can use addFieldToSelect on the collection. Is there an equivalent when using load()? When I google this I get the collection method.

Thanks,
GG

EDIT:
I just want to add that if the collection way is how it's done than that's fine. I just want to make sure it can't be done using load().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no alternative to use the collection except for rewriting the model code altogether which is probably not what you want to do.
The model load call can only be used to load a full entry - what you can specify is the attribute which to use for the load. For example:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku,'sku')
```

will load a product by its sku.

In fact the model load itself simply defers to it's resource by doing:

```
$this->_getResource()->load($this, $id, $field);
```

But the resource load method does also not provide the ability to filter for specific attributes, so you will always load the full pack or use the collection.

Comment: @gwgeller One additional suggestion for you: Instead of using the model to get the collection, you can get the collection directly. For example for products: Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

Comment: Is there any practical benefit of using the resource model directly?

Comment: @gwgeller not really, but you seemed to want it as reduced as possible. The only advantage is that the model is not instantiated in this case, so there is a little less (object-oriented) overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try loading a collection with only one item (as you are doing now), and selecting what attributes you want using:

```
addAttributeToSelect('you_attribute_code_here')
```

This will return a collection (albeit containing one item), with only the attributes you wish to have returned. Example:

```
$productIds = array(166);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

$product = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I'm wondering is if I can use getModel()->load() to do the same thing.

Comment: I've not come across a way to do that with a model (rather than a collection). You could perhaps look at rewriting the product model (in particular `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product->load()`), although it seems a more complex route